# Monodevelop iOS Unity Cannot Connect to Debugger

Tags: ios, macos, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling to get my iOS app debugging with monodevelop. The mac is connected to the same network as the iPad running the app and it shows up in the attach to process window so it is discoverable. The firewall is also turned off and the iPad does not have cellular network capability.

When I try to connect I get a "could not connect to debugger" message. Does anyone have any ideas? I've been doing lots of googling but can't find any answers.