# MonoDevelop not hitting breakpoints when attached to iOS device

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I've built my solution in MonoDevelop, then created an Xcode project in Unity with the following settings

[image]

I have then successfully deployed the app to the iPhone, stopped the Xcode project, reopened the app on the iPhone and then attached the MonoDevelop debugger

[image]

The problem is that when I set breakpoints, they show as unreachable and don't get hit at all.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this? The stress of it is killing me..
Thanks

Spec:
Macbook Air Early 2015 - El Capitan 10.11.6
iPod Touch (MGG72BT/A) - iOS 9.3.1
MonoDevelop 5.9.6
Unity 5.3.4f1

Comment: I might run into a similar issue but I cannot even get the debugger to connect to iOS 9.3.5 with MonoDevelop 5.9.6. iPhonePlayer never shows up in the processes window.

Comment: @tlindell I wouldn't hold your breath for Unity to help out. We contacted them and they basically said that we need to buy their $20k support package for them to come out and resolve it. They provide nothing less. What a joke.

Comment: Yikes, luckily for us - Stack overflow exists. I just posted my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611558/monodevelop-ios-unity-cannot-connect-to-debugger)

Comment: @mylogon I have the same problem. I'm able to attach running process but none of my breakpoint's are hit. Did you manage to solve that problem?

Comment: @mickiewicz I wish. No such luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue on Linux and I noticed that it started happening after I manually built the project in MonoDevelop, which gave me a bunch of build errors that were due to the fact that the version of .NET unity was targeting was 3.5 but the one came with MD was 4.5. So after I changed the target FW to 4.5 the build errors (in MD) cleared BUT the breakpoints stopped working.

What I did was I restarted both MD and Unity, Cleaned project in MD BUT DID NOT BUILD THEM IN MD. Just saved and switched to Unity which uses its own build. After that I switched back to MD and attached to Unity process WITHOUT BUILDING.

After this the breakpoints started working again. Conclusion - do not build the project in MD, just use it for editing scripts only and let Unity do the building.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a go on Monday.

Comment: Sadly, this has not worked with my project. If I move over to Unity after cleaning the projects in the solution, it throws a lot of errors about missing dlls that mono tends to produce, I guess. Thanks anyway.